# boolean value not changing in if else in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CommonElements
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int s1,s2,count=0;
        boolean d;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 1st array size");
        s1=sc.nextInt();
        int n1[]=new int[s1];
        System.out.println("Enter "+s1+" nos for 1st array");
        for(int i=0;i<s1;i++)
        {
            n1[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter 2nd array size");
        s2=sc.nextInt();
        int n2[]=new int[s2];
        System.out.println("Enter "+s2+" nos for 2nd array");
        for(int i=0;i<s2;i++)
        {
            n2[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<s1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<s2;j++)
            {

                if(n1[i]==n2[j])
                {
                    d=true;
                    System.out.println(n1[i]);
                }
                else
                    d=false;
            }
        }

        if(d==false)
            System.out.println("there are no common elements");


    }
}
```

This prog should return all the common elements in 2 arrays if found & should display `there are no common elements` if no common elements r found...this msg should be displayed only once so I am using boolean value. whithin the for loop the boolean value for `d` is changing but when it comes out of for loop `d` doesnt take the changed value.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your English. Please rewrite it, and for that matter, format your code.

Comment: even if there is a mach in the two arrays you will set `d=false` in the next iteration. So it will be always `false` unless the last match is equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the  `else section`

```
class CommonElements
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int s1,s2,count=0;
        boolean d = false; //Assign false to it

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter 1st array size");
        s1=sc.nextInt();
        int n1[]=new int[s1];
        System.out.println("Enter "+s1+" nos for 1st array");
        for(int i=0;i<s1;i++)
        {
            n1[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter 2nd array size");
        s2=sc.nextInt();
        int n2[]=new int[s2];
        System.out.println("Enter "+s2+" nos for 2nd array");
        for(int i=0;i<s2;i++)
        {
            n2[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int i=0;i<s1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<s2;j++)
            {

                if(n1[i]==n2[j])
                {
                    d=true;
                    System.out.println(n1[i]);
                }
                //else NO NEED OF THIS ELSE SECTION AS IF YOUR LAST 
                                    // COMPARISON DO NOT MATCHES THEN IT WILL REASSIGN FALSE VALUE
                //d=false;
            }
        }

        if(d==false)
            System.out.println("there are no common elements");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your following section is outside of two for loop. Bring it back to first for loop, than you can view the changes.

```
if(d==false)
System.out.println("there are no common elements");
```

Comment: if i do that then to its not taking the changed value...if i dont use boolean then the msg will be reapeated till the for loop ends.

Comment: Please, debug your code, that will be best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following (since I also have trouble reading your question):

You have common elements but the output is still `there are no common elements`, right?

The problem is this: you compare the elements index by index but only the last index wins, since you're setting d to false in the else block.

Consider this case: array A = [1,2] and array B = [1,3]

You now loop over A and B and thus have the following checks:

- 1 == 1 -> true
- 1 == 3 -> false
- 2 == 1 -> false
- 2 == 3 -> false

This leads to `d` being false, since in effect only the last comparison matters.

Remove the else block and it should work fine (unless there are other errors I didn't spot yet). Thus you initialize d with false, i.e. you assume there are no common elements. Once you find some, you set d to true and might even break the loops, since you found the information you're looking for (there is at least one pair of common elements).

Alternatively count the pairs of common elements and check whether that number is 0 or greater. This would provide the additional information of how many pairs were found.

*Edit*: as an additional hint on code formatting, I personally find it easier to always use braces for loops as well as if-else blocks. That way you can reduce errors that might accidentially introduced by trying to add another statement into a single-element block (i.e. no braces). That's just personal tast/experience however so YMMV.

*Important note:* if you remove the else block, initialize your variable `d`, otherwise it won't compile (`d` might get initialized then).

Comment: im getting the common elements correctly...the problem is when there are no common elemnts the msg is not displayed...

Comment: @user2987459 did you check the value of `d` just before printing? I'm pretty sure there are some common elements in the arrays (according to how your code defines "common").

Comment: Correction: please check whether `d` really is _never_ set to true?

Comment: i v assigned no value to d in the start...iv just declared it as boolean d

Comment: hey i got the solution...i used System.exit(0) after the else instead of using boolean to display the msg

Comment: @user2987459 it would have been good to post your _actual_ code then.